# PHP/JQUERY label to input in while loop on edit button click

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm using php/jquery and html my requirement is when I click on edit button, label should be replaced with input text and I would be able to update in my mysql db and if I click on cancel button input to label..

Following is my code:

```
<?php 
    $sql = 'select * from demo';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
?>
    <label style="display:block;">abc</label>
    <input type="text" style="display:none;"/>

    <button id="edit">edit</button>
    <button id="cancel">cancel</button>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

suppose If I display 10 records from mysql db, for each record I should be able to edit on particularly clicked row.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: In a loop you should not use same ids!!! change the id attribute of button to class.

Comment: i would you suggest you to keep an `<a>`  instead of the button for both edit and cancel and then pass some id which is fetched from mysql and add that as the href of `<a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap each label in a parent (for example a `p`).

On a click, you hide the label and add a input and two buttons to the parent.

By clicking the cancel button, the label gets visible again and the other elements will be removed.

The "tricky" part is the submit button. You'll need a PHP page that processes the data you post to it. Then when it succeeds you should echo an `ok` . The `$.post` function knows a `success` argument. This function will check if the returned value will be `ok`, and if so, changes the text from the label, shows it, and removes the other items.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.edit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this) ,
        label = elem.prev('label') ,
        parent = elem.parent() ,
        value = label.text() ,
        input = '<input type="text" value="'+value+'" />' ,
        save = '<button class="save">Save</button>' ,
        cancel = '<button class="cancel">Cancel</button>';
    parent.children().hide();
    parent.append(input+save+cancel);
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.cancel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this) ,
        parent = elem.parent() ,
        label = parent.find('label');
    parent.children(':not(label,.edit)').remove();
    parent.children().show();
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.save', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this) ,
        parent = elem.parent() ,
        label = parent.find('label') ,
        value = parent.find('input').val();
    parent.addClass('active');
    
    var data = '&name='+value;
    $.post("processingPage.php", data)
    .success( function(returnedData) {
      if( returnedData == 'ok' ) { /* change this to check if the data was processed right */
        var active = $('.active');
        active.find('label').text( active.find('input').val() );
        active.children(':not(label,.edit)').remove();
        active.children.show();
      }
    });
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><label>Some text</label><button class="edit">Edit</button></p>
<p><label>Some text</label><button class="edit">Edit</button></p>
<p><label>Some text</label><button class="edit">Edit</button></p>
<p><label>Some text</label><button class="edit">Edit</button></p>
```

You're PHP would look like this:

```
<?php
$return = false;
if( isset( $_POST['name'] ) ) {
   if( mysqli_query( ... ) ) {
       $return = true;
   }
}
if( $return ) 
   echo 'ok';
else
   echo 'not ok';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out it was really helpful ur code!! one small change i would like to get clarified from u. can i use edit button instead of clicking on label text! i mean when i click on edit button label should be placed with input text box thanks!!